What does 'Universal Election' mean?
I web-searched the expression, 'universal election', used on SE-BH, but without success. I keep finding information about 'universal salvation' which, I assume, is not the same thing.
I am interested in when this expression was coined and by whom.
I am aware that some say 'election' means that God foresaw who would 'choose Christ' and by looking into the future, as it were, he 'chose' those who would, in time, make this decision.
I am also aware that some say 'election' conveys the concept that the Father, before the foundation of the world, purposed to beget sons and purposed to bring them to glory.
But I have only today read the words 'universal election' and I am interested in which Christian groups use the word and what they, themselves, would understand by the term, and when it became common parlance.

I also could find nothing regarding the term "universal election" in searching the web.  However, I did find the following within a SE-BH answer which uses the term and it seems fairly well defined there as God's desire to save all mankind as evidenced by His offer of grace to all through the Gospel even though many will reject Him:

let me say that universal election does NOT mean universal salvation - far from it. While God want to save all people, many will reject God's free offer of salvation and thus be eternally lost... The Bible frequently makes this same point of wanting to save all people by emphasizing that God does not show favoritism but treats all people impartially...Thus, God “elected” all people by extending His Grace to everyone, even before they sinned! Further, God did this without any input from us, nor request from us, nor consultation with sinners. Unfortunately, many will reject this wonderful, free offer.

The appendix offered in the answer well establishes God's revealed desire for everyone to repent and believe but it makes a poor case for this being the correct understanding of 'election' itself.
It remains to be seen if this theological construct is denominational in nature or merely a phrase coined by a single individual.

Even among those denominations that believe in "God's desire to save all mankind" and in "extending His Grace to everyone" there will be disagreements over when it happens. E.g. "even before they sinned" vs. only a few during this age and everyone else during the Millennium and following the second resurrection.

I cannot imagine how a creator decides to create knowing mankind will transgress and fall into sin. Hard to comprehend intentionally building a car engine that will start up, run for a few moments, crap itself, then knowing that whilst fixing the engine, it's going to take ones life. Who would build an engine like that? Gods love is hard to comprehend.

@adam If we take your manufacturing analogy (which of course has limits), imagine you produce a product that is incredibly valuable, but the process has a high scrap rate, and cannot be improved. Is it still worth producing?

@adam Imagine you are manufacturing a car engine that is designed to have choice.

Up-voted and agreed as the answer. Yes, agreed that the article you refer to makes a poor case in regard to what the word 'election' means, as used in scripture, particularly by, firstly, Jesus of Nazareth and then by Paul the Apostle. If election means what many of us understand it to mean then 'unconditional election' is a contradiction in terms. I intend, in the will of the Lord, to follow this up some more. Your balanced answer is much appreciated, Michael.
